# Spring.NET & Alternatives

Tags: inversion-of-control, spring.net

Is Spring.NET a good framework to use in web development?

Are there alternatives?

Update (for Frederik):

- Are there drawbacks when using Spring.NET (or IoC container) in Web Development. I always used spring.actionscript in client side flex applications, but client applications aren't the same as Web Applications.
- Is there a Microsoft IoC Containter Framework?
- How does it handle concurrency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Spring.NET committer I am biased of course, but Spring.Web was entirely built and refined out of our own needs over the past years. Imho it provides the broadest support compared to other containers when it comes to WebForms development. MVC support is still TDB though.

Spring.NET itself also is entirely thread-safe. Of course your own singleton implementations need to be threadsafe, if not you can always use "request" scope.

hth,
Erich

Answer (score 3):

"Is there a Microsoft IoC Containter Framework?"
- Yes, it's called [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468366.aspx)

Comment: Do you have experience with Unity? Or is it outdated?

Comment: Nope haven't used it myself, we use Spring.Net. I don't believe Unity is outdated, as far as I know it's fairly new, so wouldn't worry about using it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a good framework ?  Depends on your requirements.

Are there alternatives ? Yes.
(Castle Windsor, StructureMap, PicoContainer, ...).

[Google](http://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&rlz=1C1CHMG_nlBE291BE303&q=IoC+container+frameworks+for+.NET&btnG=Zoeken&meta=) can show you the way ...